# Send Audio data with SMS in android

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send an audio file converted to a byte array with SMS using SMSManager.sendDataMessage.

But, I am unable to send it to other phone. Can any suggest how can I do it?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

SMS is for text based messages 160 character limit, but you could use MMS to send the Audio file itself as an attachment that is downloadable.

Try something like this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");     
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url)); // url would point to mp3 file
sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
```

Good References:

- http://snipt.net/Martin/tag/android

Comment: Can I send the MMS without the user interaction as in case of SMS using SMSManager

Comment: Can you suggest which API does MMS use to send without user interaction pls ??